# Generating summary report from an excel list

Tags: excel, report, lookup

I need a help from more advanced Excel users for using lookup features. In one worksheet I have a list of programs installed on various computers. For example:

```
Program     Computer
Office 2010 YOGI
Safari      YOGI
Chrome      YOGI
Firefox     YOGI
Office 2010 MIKI
Chrome      MIKI
Thunderbird MIKI
Chrome      PLUTO
Office 2003 PLUTO
Internet Ex PLUTO
```

I need a way to check if given program is installed on given computer and create simillar table:

```
Progr/Comp  YOGI    MIKI    PLUTO
Office 2010  Yes    Yes 
Safari       Yes        
Firefox      Yes        
Chrome       Yes    Yes     Yes
Thunderbird                 Yes 
Office 2003                 Yes
Internet Ex                 Yes
```

So I need a function to lookup in given range for a given program name (this funkction should return a range of cell, first table can be sorted by a program name), and then lookup in this result set for a given computer name.

Any help will be appreciatied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Run a pivot table on your data,
- put the computer name as the column field,
- the program as row field,
- the computer name again as a data field.

You'll get 1 / 0 instead of yes / blank, but it will be easier to update and maintain that any hard-coded lookup.

Comment: Thank you for your sugestion. Pivot table works great, but ... my example was little oversimplified. In reality, table with program names contains names as "7Zip 4.57" "7Zip 6.32" etc. I want that all versions of the same program (f.e. 7Zip) was reported as single program, no matther wat version it is. So I have manually prepared kolumn with program names with stripped version info.

Comment: I have modified program names column in source table, so it solves my mproblem. Thank you.